# Crossfade animation on css text background-clip (webkit)

Tags: css, webkit, css-transitions

I'm using this code to overlay the background image onto `h2` (leaving a white background):

```
h2:hover {
      -webkit-background-clip: text;
      -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

If I try to animate this using `transition:5s all` and hover over it, the background immediately switches to white, leaving the text's overlay fading in. Is there any way I can crossfade the two events (background becoming white, background overlaying text)?

Comment: You can comma separate transitions and their respective properties. More code or a JSFiddle would be helpful. http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transition/

Answer (score 0):

You can comma separate transition properties.

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/uDeXY/)

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusantium maiores ipsum itaque labore laborum natus a deleniti harum repellat enim! Saepe ut asperiores eum velit!</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    padding:25px;
    background-color: lightblue;
    font-size:2rem;
    height:250px;
    transition: 
        background-color 2s ease,
        font-size 2s 1s ease;
}

div:hover {
    background-color: green;
    font-size:1rem;

}
```

http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transition/